# How to create a nested HTML structure shown below using WCM Menu/Nav component?

Tags: html, wcm, ibm-wcm

I am designing a carousel with three images. I need to implment following code using WCM. I am able to design with a single result design. Please guide me how to get three links in a set. All the images are in the same site area.

```
<div class="subBox">
    <div class="set">
        <div class="images"><img src='slide1.jpg' alt='' /></div>
        <div class="images"><img src='slide2.jpg' alt='' /></div>
        <div class="images"><img src='slide3.jpg' alt='' /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="set">
        <div class="images"><img src='slide4.jpg' alt='' /></div>
        <div class="images"><img src='slide5.jpg' alt='' /></div>
        <div class="images"><img src='slide6.jpg' alt='' /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="set">
        <div class="images"><img src='slide7.jpg' alt='' /></div>
        <div class="images"><img src='slide8.jpg' alt='' /></div>
        <div class="images"><img src='slide9.jpg' alt='' /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a List Presentation in a Menu / Navigator - depending on whether you need to preserve the order. Set the maximum number of 9.

**Header:**

```
<div class="subBox">
  <div class="set">
```

**Item Layout:**

```
[Plugin:Matches pattern="(3|6)" text="[Placeholder tag='listnum']"]
  </div>
  <div class="set">
[/Plugin:Matches]
    <div class="images">[Element type="content" context="autofill" key="img"]</div>
```

**Footer:**

```
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

So you have one *sitearea* under this *sitearea* there is a set of *content*.

There is nothing out of the box can do it for you.

### First Solution(Using Javascript)

- render all Images in one hidden Div
- add some java script code to construct your HTML

### Second solution(Creating Custom Plugin)

- Create custom plugin and pass to it **index of the item** and **sublist items number** and it only renders it's body if ("index" mod "Sublist items number" equal zero), you can get index from [Placeholder tag="listnum" htmlencode="false"]
  and in your case "Sublist items number" is 3
- In menu design *`header ="<div class="subBox"><div class="set">"`*
  in design for each result render your item then use your custom plugin to render " " -> will render every 3 items
  design for footer *`"</div></div>"`*